# Yii model findAll() and count() return different number of results

Tags: yii

UPDATED: see the end of the question

I'm working with Yii (and RESTFullYii in particular but I doubt that is relevant to the question)

There is a CDbCriteria for a model:

```php
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria(
                array(
                        'together' => true,
                        'with' => array(
                            'roles'=> array(
                                'having' => "roles.role IN ($userRoles)"
                                ))
                    )
            );
        $count = $model->count($criteria);
        $result= $model->findAll($criteria);
```

While the `findAll()` method returns only 3 records (which is good) the `count()` method returns 13 which is the total number of records in the table represented by the `$model`

I've enabled query logging in MySQL and I found out that the two query generated by Yii is completely different

```sql
SELECT `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`,
       `t`.`name` AS `t0_c1`,
       `t`.`description` AS `t0_c2`,
       `t`.`enabled` AS `t0_c3`,
       `t`.`issuegroup_id` AS `t0_c4`,
       `t`.`role_id_exec` AS `t0_c5`,
       `t`.`require_attachment` AS `t0_c6`,
       `roles`.`id` AS `t1_c0`,
       `roles`.`role` AS `t1_c1`,
       `roles`.`enabled` AS `t1_c2`,
       `roles`.`description` AS `t1_c3`
FROM `issuetype` `t`
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `role_has_issuetype` `roles_roles` ON
         (`t`.`id`=`roles_roles`.`issuetype_id`)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `role` `roles` ON
         (`roles`.`id`=`roles_roles`.`role_id`)
HAVING (roles.role IN ('user'))
LIMIT 100
```

The other query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `t`.`id`)
FROM `issuetype` `t`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `role_has_issuetype` `roles_roles` ON
    (`t`.`id`=`roles_roles`.`issuetype_id`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `role` `roles` ON
    (`roles`.`id`=`roles_roles`.`role_id`)
```

Is this the normal behavior for the `findAll()` and `count()` methods or did I do something I shouldn't have done or is this a bug in Yii?

And how to get the actual count of the records properly?

`count($model->findAll($criteria))` seems to be working fine but is this the correct solution or is it just a workaround?

(From a performance viewpoint I think it might be better than the actual `count()` because I'm running the same query twice which is cached by the MySQL server)

**UPDATE**:
I've asked the same question on GitHub and Paul Klimov kindly pointed out that it is unnecessary for the 'having' and 'group' clauses to be in the joined table and it is perfectly OK to move it out of the 'with' see it here: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/3297

Comment: I can't say why the values are different, but I use count($result) all the time without issue. That usage is perfectly all right.

Comment: @crafter thanks for the input, at least I know I'm safe with this method :)

Comment: The problem with count($result) is that if you have pagination, then the count will only have the number of paginated entries. in your example the count will be maximum 100 since a limit is applied on the request.

Comment: Based on the sample code, you're able to use WHERE instead of HAVING, which I think would solve the problem. But as others have mentioned, you're probably best off upgrading to the latest version of Yii. Also, keep in mind Yii2 is very close to its beta release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yii had some problem with `Having` criteria while using `count` method from `ActiveRecord`, but it is fixed in newer Yii versions: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/pull/2167

Comment: I'm using 1.1.14 in the CHANGELOG I've found "Bug #2201: Cannot use "having" with bound params in CActiveRecord::count() (ivokund)" which refers to the issue you've linked...but it seems that it's still not working properly. I'll start a discussion there. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clone your model before count() or findAll() method applying:

```
$result= $model->findAll($criteria);
$modelClone = clone $model;
$count = $model->count($criteria);
```