# Yii2 db query builder having into where

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, having, yii2-basic-app

Sorry on my English. I add new condition to my query like this:

```
$query->andWhere(['or',
            ["<", "o.score", $score_operator],
            ["<", "d.score", $score_delivery],
            ["<", "SUM(sd.score)/count(DISTINCT sd.id)",$score_dishes]]);
```

Buth I got error:

```
General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function
```

Then I read that I must use having in 3-d row, but I don't know how to put  "having" in "where" condition.

Comment: Have a look on the answer here = > [Having Yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22598436/yii-model-findall-and-count-return-different-number-of-results?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: do you have the normal `sql` query prepared ? if yes please share your actual query  in your post that you are trying to build

Answer (score 1):

For condition/filter related  to aggregation function  you should use having and not where

```
$query->having("SUM(sd.score)/count(DISTINCT sd.id) < " .$score_dishes);
```

where work on table rows  having work on selected  result rows. 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#having()-detail

starting for 2.0.11  you could use also  filteHaving in case you having http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#filterHaving()-detail